# Gratis USB drive app to save/restore a partition

Tags: gratis, backup

I am looking for an app that runs from a bootable USB stick and will let me save and restore a partition (to/from an external hard-drive).

That's it.

---

If you want additional info, I want to have a rescue US stick for my Widows install.

Not the entire disk, just one partition (c:\ - there are tother partitions on the same disk).

A bonus would be to be able to copy individual files from one to the other & back again. Or, indeed, to view file contents, etc, but that is just "nice to have" and very low runner.

But, really, just 100% rock-solid "clone partition, with no problems with open files" is sufficient.

Comment: My first thought was [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/). Can be installed on a stick, and has a lot of tools aboard to rescue Windows systems. Not sure if it ships with the `partimage` package or if that was replaced by something other, though – has been a long time I last looked at it. Ah, I see, they're using [Partclone](https://partclone.org/) now. Well, then it should be a good fit to take a look at.